# How to create a VS 2008 Windows Forms project programmatically, that can be maintained just like any other project created manually

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have a bunch of control properties (type of control, location, size, etc.) derived as a text file from an old system on a different platform. I thought it would be fairly easy to load these "control descriptions" into a Windows Forms project in VS 2008 and then be able to maintain the new project in VS just as if it had been created manually.

I'm familiar with using VS and C# but it I'm not sure where to start with this.

I searched the web and found a number of articles about creating controls on forms at run time and that is not so hard, given the information I have, but I want the created form to be a permanent part of a Win Forms project, so I need to get what was created at run time into VS, and accessible in the project just as if it had been manually dropped on the designer surface. Is there a way I could create these forms with a program and then "save" them in a form acceptable to VS?

I manually created a windows Form project to try and use as a "template" and identify how VS does it. I have tried to understand the contents and the relationships between the various resource files, but it is a bit too much. There are also warnings that various files are created by VS and should not be amended manually.

I have almost 1000 forms from the old system so the thought of manually having to add each one to VS is pretty non-viable. I could translate the text descriptions into XML if there is a way to feed an XML description of a Form into a VS Forms project...?

Any advice\direction towards this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at T4 Text Templates, VS2008 supports them. You would write a T4 program (in C#) that reads your XML form descriptions and converts them into WinForms files - essentially your own version of `InitializeComponent`. If you keep the same source-code pattern as the "real" `foo.designer.cs` files then you can use the WinForms designer with them too.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I got a bit frightened when I saw the disclaimer in foo.designer.cs but I have since done a few experiments and I think it is "doable". I did look at T4  Templates a while back but I just don't have time right now to go round the learning curve. I'll make a template out of an existing Windows Form and then amend it, I think. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

VS uses code generation to create controls in Windows Forms. If you look at a form e.g. `Form1` that's in your project, it consists of three files, `Form1.cs`, `Form1.designer.cs` and `Form1.resx`. The `Form1.designer.cs` file contains the construction of the controls in the `InitializeComponent` method. VS executes this and parses it at design time to give you the design view of the form where you can make modifications. You could write a program to parse your text files and generate C# code for `InitializeComponent` to get the right effect. There are various options but you probably would want to use the `CSharpCodeProvider` class.

Another option is to use WPF. Forms are designed in WPF using XAML, which is an XML based format. (By that I mean, an XAML document is also a valid XML document, but the reverse is not true.) If you create a WPF project and add some controls to it then you could take a look at the XAML file to get an idea of the structure.

Comment: Thanks Erik, this was very helpful. I had already done what you suggested in looking at the various files but it got a bit bewildering and the disclaimer about not messing with generated code put me off. I have revisited it since reading your post and the world didn't end when I amended foo.designer.cs so I feel a bit more confident :-) I like the XAML idea  with WPF but I have never used WPF so again there is a learning curve. Win Forms seems to be nice and basic for Windows so I'll probably go that route.  Never heard of the CSharpCodeProvider Class so I'll take a look at that too. Thanks.